# How to to cast XElement to GUID using System.Type?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

For example I have XElement looks like this:

```
<Id>5E64F866-823E-4B2F-AE7D-D780444011E9</Id>
```

And I need to convert it to System.Guid. I know that I can do this using explicit conversion:

```
var xElem = xElement.Parse("<Id>5E64F866-823E-4B2F-AE7D-D780444011E9</Id>");
var myGuid = (Guid)xElem;
```

But what I actually need is:

```
var guidType = typeof(Guid);
var xElem = xElement.Parse("<Id>5E64F866-823E-4B2F-AE7D-D780444011E9</Id>");
var myGuid = xElem.ConvertToObject(guidType); // for example, pseudo method
```

I use reflection in my code, and I need ability to set value to the property using propertyInfo.SetValue(object, object). The possible types of value I set to the property is always one of the type XElement explicit conversion supports([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit(v=vs.110).aspx)). Hope someone understand my question:)

Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: I did not understand what you asked for, maybe myGuid = new Guid(xElem.InnerText) etc will help?

Comment: I need to convert XElement value to Guid using System.Type without explicit conversion

Answer (score 0):

The XElement DOM does not support binding attributes or body to a particular type.  It'll always be a string.

Assuming what you've provided is just a simplified example though, the below might help you would in a more complex scenario.

```
IEnumerable<Guid> ids = from e in d.Root.Elements()
                        where e.Name == (ns + "employee")
                        select new Guid(e.Attribute("Id").Value);
```

Or you could design up an extension method to XElement which would see if the passed type has a constructor which takes in a string through reflection and call it.  That's a bit more complex though.